# How to print many random lists at the same time

Tags: c#, random

I need to generate a random list of letters, and then I need to list another different list.

I am using the following code, and every time I call the method it gives me the same list in one run..How can I get different lists in one run? I tried to put the methods with 2 different names then call each one, but the resulting lists still the same.

```
using System; 

class GFG 
{ 
static int MAX = 26; 

// Returns a String of random alphabets of 
// length n. 
static String printRandomString(int n) 
{ 
    char []alphabet = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 
                        'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',  
                        'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 
                        'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' }; 

    Random random = new Random(); 
    String res = ""; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
        res = res + alphabet[(int)(random.Next(0, MAX))]; 

    return res; 
} 

// Driver code 
public static void Main() 
{ 
    int n = 10; 
    Console.Write(printRandomString(n)); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Should be: `res = res + alphabet[(random.nextInt(MAX))];`. The [**next(int bits)**](https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-random-next-method) method is used to generate the next ***pseudorandom*** number.

Comment: @Memo what output you are expect?

Comment: That code doesn't compile in **Java**. Looks more like C++/C# code (`using System`, `random.Next`, `Main()`, `Console.Write`).

Comment: @DevilsHnd Thank u but this not working is c#

Comment: @Rahul_Patil I expect the output to be 2 ldifferent lists..In Main() if write     Console.Write(printRandomString(n)); 
    Console.Write(printRandomString(n));
The output should give 2 different lists

Comment: @Andreas yes I need at least the idea in any language.

Comment: This is not Java code! What language are you writing this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Time Generate a new Name:

```
const int MAX = 26; 

string printRandomString(int n) 
{ 
    char alphabet[MAX] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 
                          'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',  
                          'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 
                          'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' }; 



    string res = ""; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
        res = res + alphabet[rand() % MAX];     //this line generate every time new name


    return res; 
}
```

Comment: @Memo above code is generate the different list of item

Answer (score 1):

I just copied/pasted your code verbatim into a fiddle to check and ran it.

Here are the result from a few consecutive runs...

```
run #1:> snqeiyxkkt
run #2:> uunzajkcjf
run #3:> xassjivukf
run #4:> dnaosumxeq
```

Is that what you were expecting? If not, can you clarify the issue you are experiencing?

**Edit**

Following comments below from @Memo and @Andreas, I did a little bit more investigating.

I am guessing the code in this question is C#?

If that is the case, then it is using the .Net Framework `Random` class. [See here for API doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random).

@Memo gives the example that calling the following two lines together...

```
Console.Write(printRandomString(n)); 
Console.Write(printRandomString(n));
```

...results in the two same lists in output.

Reading the API doc for `Random`, we see the following paragraphs that explain why this is the case.

*Note, I've cropped some of the paragraph text here to keep it brief, you can read the full text using the link to the API doc above*

> In .NET Framework, the default seed value is time-dependent. In .NET Core, the default seed value is produced by the thread-static, pseudo-random number generator.
>
> If the same seed is used for separate Random objects, they will generate the same series of random numbers.
>
> the parameterless Random() constructor uses the system clock to generate its seed value. However, on the .NET Framework only, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers.
>
> On most Windows systems, Random objects created within 15 milliseconds of one another are likely to have identical seed values.

Here is the solution they recommend in the API docs...

> To avoid this problem, create a single Random object instead of multiple objects. Note that the Random class in .NET Core does not have this limitation.
>
> **Avoiding multiple instantiations**
>
> On the .NET Framework, initializing two random number generators in a tight loop or in rapid succession creates two random number generators that can produce identical sequences of random numbers. In most cases, this is not the developer's intent and can lead to performance issues, because instantiating and initializing a random number generator is a relatively expensive process.
>
> Both to improve performance and to avoid inadvertently creating separate random number generators that generate identical numeric sequences, we recommend that you create one Random object to generate many random numbers over time, instead of creating new Random objects to generate one random number.

---

**Example solution for @Memo's code.**

```
using System; 

public class GFG 
{ 
    static int MAX = 26; 

    // moving declaration of random up here means it is only created once
    static Random random = new Random(); 

    // Returns a String of random alphabets of 
    // length n. 
    static String printRandomString(int n) 
    { 
        char []alphabet = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 
                            'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',  
                            'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 
                            'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' }; 

        // random used to be declared here but we moved it up above
        String res = ""; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
            res = res + alphabet[(int)(random.Next(0, MAX))]; 

        return res; 
    } 

    // Driver code 
    public static void Main() 
    { 
        int n = 10; 
        Console.Write(printRandomString(n)); 
        // add these lines below to demonstrate it's working
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write(printRandomString(n));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please do the same by writing this 2 times in Main():
    Console.Write(printRandomString(n)); 
    Console.Write(printRandomString(n));
You will get 2 same lists in output

Comment: @Memo Probably because each call creates a new `Random`, which auto-seeds itself from the system clock, and the two calls happen so fast, the clock hasn't ticked yet. Try moving the `Random` to a `static` field to see if that makes any difference. In Java, I recommend using [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html), but your code isn't Java, despite the question tag claiming otherwise.

Comment: Yes, @Andreas has some good thoughts here. Memo, is your code C# by any chance?

Comment: I have edited my answer above based on the comments here. Let me know if this helps.